# Как сохранить в кэш добавление в базу данных в yii2?

Tags: yii2

Проблема такая, у меня после сохранения висит много запросов к БД. Сохранил 4 категории и 10 связных продуктов, и висит 35 запросов. Прочитал много статей, почти везде говорят про кэширование.

Как его реализовать правильно, примеров нигде не нашел нормальных. Понимаю, возможно не правильно что то делаю, надеюсь вы подтолкнете меня в правильное русло)) За ранее спасибо вам!

**Модель Category**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "{{%category}}".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $name
 *
 * @property Product[] $products
 */
class Category extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%category}}';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id'], 'primaryKey'],
            [['name'], 'required'],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['name'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Products]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::className(), ['category_id' => 'id']);
    }

}
```

**модель Product**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "{{%product}}".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string|null $name
 * @property int $category_id
 *
 * @property Category $category
 */
class Product extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%product}}';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['category_id'], 'required'],
            [['category_id'], 'integer'],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['name'], 'unique'],
            [['category_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Category::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['category_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'category_id' => 'Category ID',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Category]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
    }
}
```

**controller**

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;


use yii\db\Exception;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\components\parseDigiseller;
use app\models\Category;
use app\models\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller{

   public function actionIndex(){
        $host="../components/files/products.csv";
        $file='сайт получения информации';

        $parse = new parseDigiseller();
        $resParse = $parse->parseDigi($file, $host);

       foreach ($resParse as $saveData){
           $categoryModel = new Category();
           $categoryModel->name = $saveData['category'];
           $categoryModel->save();
       }

       $category = Category::find()->all();
       foreach ($resParse as $saveData){
           foreach ($category as $cat) {
               if($cat['name'] === $saveData['category']) {
                   $id = $cat['id'];

                   $productModel = new Product();
                   $productModel->name = $saveData['name'];
                   $productModel->category_id = $id;
                   $productModel->save();
               }
           }
       }

        return $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не знаю как правильно это назвать. В дебагере Yii2 35 запросов. После сохранения. Это очень много, это нагрузка на базу данных же

Comment: blacknife вы знаете вообще Yii2? Работали там?

Comment: поверь 35 запросов это еще очень даже немного

Comment: От одного пользователя это очень много, а если будет 1000, это 35000. Да и зачем они мне? Я сохранил все данные, все, мне они не нужны. Блин, да зачем вы с вами разводим эти пустые разговоры. Код я дал, если есть решение, помогите, нет, ну нет. Если что то добавить надо, добавлю.

Comment: простой совет, почитайте и узнайте про кэширование для начала и уже потом делайте выводы, старайтесь избегать кэширования, пока в этом не будет прямой необходимости!!!, это простая техника, но это снижает гибкость приложения, не делайте лишнюю работу заранее, но закладывайте возможность использования кэширования в будущем, файловый кэш вам никакого прироста не даст, в memcache и прочие штуки вы явно лезть не готовы

Comment: Причем тут почитать про кэш? Я задал конкретный вопрос, зачем вот это тут обсуждать? Мне нужен ответ на вопрос, а не нравоучения не по теме

Comment: `надеюсь вы подтолкнете меня в правильное русло` - это не ваши ли слова? мои комментарии как раз по вашей теме, если хотите четкий ответ на вопрос - задайте его правильно с примерами кода ваших попыток и указанием конкретно что не получается

Comment: еще и минус нажал, классный "помощник"......... Поражают подобные люди, везде, лишь бы что то сказать и все равно

Comment: так на будущее, подтолкнуть, это дать какую то информацию, которая поможет решить вопрос. А не нравоучения, которые только разжигают конфликты

Comment: так вам здесь точно никто не поможет, помните про нормы поведения на площадке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: Я нормально общаюсь. В отличии от вас. Я еще раз повторяюсь, надо что то дополнить, дополню, объясните что. Я все написал. Мне нужно после сохранения, сохранить в кэш то, что я сохранил, чтобы не было лишних подключений к бд. Я не знаю что тут не понятного.... Просто дать пример, чтобы человек понял, а не запутывать его еще больше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятна суть контроллера, но постараюсь донести мысль насколько я понял ситуацию. Судя по коду, данные категорий и продуктов лежат в файле и при запросе экшена добавляются в БД. Скорее всего это единичная операция. Если данные файла будут изменяться, тогда надо делать проверку, чтобы не добавить дублей в БД (это по категориям, для продуктов может и допустимо).

Если не нравится большое количество запросов при сохранении, то можно не сохранять каждую запись отдельно, а подготовить массив данных для категорий и продуктов и использовать метод `batchInsert($columns, $items)`, так будет всего два запроса. При этом не будет валидации данных. Если данные в из файла надо валидировать, то перед добавлением в массив `$items` можно создавать объект модели (категории или продукта), грузить туда данные, делать валидацию и по результату уже добавлять или нет в `$items`. Соответственно логировать, если что-то не добавили и по какой причине. Также необходимо учитывать, что при использовании `batchInsert()` не будут вызваны события, которые вызываются при выполнении метода `save()`. Вероятно это можно как-то обработать дополнительно, но надо больше информации.

Запрос `$category = Category::find()->all();` избыточен, потому что чуть выше уже есть `$categoryModel`. Достаточно их сложить в массив `$category[] = $categoryModel` и получится все тоже самое, только без запроса.

Обычно кэш применяется при получении данных. Если процесс трудоемкий, то данные пишут в кэш и получают оттуда, чтобы не нагружать БД. В случае записи данных в БД непонятно как и где применять возможности кэша.

1. Получаем данные
2. Формируем массив для добавления в БД (проводим валидацию)
3. Пишем данные в БД

Если не устраивает пакетное добавление данных через `batchInsert()`, тогда тут может подойти метод `link()`, при наличии сохраненной категории и соответствующих реляций в моделях.

Также хочу заметить, что все это необходимо делать не в экшене контроллера, а создать какой-то сервис, в котором все это и реализовать.

Comment: спасибо за подробные разъяснения. Да, наверное кэш тут не очень важен, это же по сути админка, сюда пользователь обращаться не будет, кэшировать надо данные из таблицы.

Единственное `$category[] = $categoryModel` вот так не сохраняется ни один продукт. Подробнее почитаю чуть позже, посплю, с ночи пришел, голова не соображает